# How do i turn ran_points into a string, it appears to still be "type"

Tags: python, string, selenium

I want to turn ran_points into a string so i can use the length function on it, it doesnt let me as it comes up with an error saying that ran_points is "type", how do i fix this. Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.footballwebpages.co.uk/rangers/form-guide")
time.sleep(3)
#Scrape results from website

ran_points = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[@title="Rangers"]')
str(ran_points)
print(ran_points.text)
length = len(ran_points)

driver.quit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Computing/Python/ScorePredicter/Test.py", line 14, in <module>
    length = len(ran_points)
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
3 Rangers W 2-1 L 2-1 W 1-0 D 2-2 L 1-0 W 1-0 6 3 1 2 7 6 +1 10

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Output^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assign `ran_points` to it's string representation. Simply change `str(ran_points)` to `ran_points = str(ran_points)`

Comment: Yup, looking back on my previous questions i can see i have done pretty much the same thing twice. Thanks for your help anyway